# Error 2911: Could not remove the folder C:\Config.Msi\

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix4

I have a installation which creates a desktop shortcut:

```
<Shortcut Id="SC.Desktop" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="!(bind.Property.ProductName)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Target="[INSTALLDIR]testfile.txt" />

<RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="integer" Name="DesktopIcon" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
```

On a installation all works fine, no errors in verbose log.

On a unistallation I get an error in verbose log:

```
DEBUG: Error 2911:  Could not remove the folder C:\Config.Msi\.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's not an actual error message. It's just the Windows Installer talking to itself. Files and folders like that are usually cleaned up on restart.

Comment: Strange. Why it is a "error" when it is no error. With admin privileges the error message is not in the log file. Can you explain it a little bit more why I should "ignore" this error message?

Comment: Addition: When uninstalling, it also takes a long time to remove the shortcut.

Comment: 1. It's not an error. But some small piece in the Windows Installer decided to report the message before some higher level piece decided that it was not an error. Easy to do when building a large system. 2. Something is probably holding your shortcut in use preventing it from being deleted.